# Effective index for filtering and sorting by date

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query, multi-index

I use mongo `4.2.10`

There is a collection `sales` with the following data:

```json
{
    "_id": ObjectId("501f1f77bcf86cd799439011"),
    "status": "BILLED",
    "sellerId": ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439011"),
    "productType": "BIKE",
    "saleDate": ISODate("2013-10-02T01:11:18.965Z"),
    ...
}
```

So imagine this table contains like 1 billion of records.
I have a requirement to select data by filtering by `saleDate` and sorting by `status, sellerId, productType, saleDate` with pagination. This request is fixed and never changes.

So I do like

```js
db.sales.find({
    saleDate: {$gte: ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"), 
               $lte: ISODate("2020-02-01T00:00:00.000Z")}
}).sort({
    status: 1,
    sellerId: 1,
    productType: 1,
    saleDate: 1
}).skip(0).limit(1000);
```

The problem I see related to index.

The following index:

```json
{
    saleDate: 1,
    status: 1,
    sellerId: 1,
    productType: 1
}
```

It would effectively search by `saleDate`, but sorting will be ineffective? Because of `saleDate` many different values it will cause index tree to be very ineffective and index itself will eat memory? I have no idea what would be better and how to create the most effective index here.

Answer (score 0):

To build an efficient index for your query, you want to follow the The [ESR (Equality, Sort, Range) Rule](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/equality-sort-range-rule/#the-esr--equality--sort--range--rule)

When creating compound indexes, the first fields should be fields you are doing exact matches on, followed by fields you are sorting on, and finally contain fields you are doing range queries on.

The $gte and $lte are considered ranged based queries.

Therefore, the best index for this query will most likely be

```
{ 
  status: 1,
  sellerId: 1,
  productType: 1,
  saleDate: 1
}
```